# Wrong height when adding autolayout subview in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I am trying to add a subview to an existing view. I am basically adding a subview to mimic an ActionSheet like this example:

http://cocoaallocinit.com/2014/03/23/implementing-a-custom-uiactionsheet

This example works fine as long as I do not use autolayout on the custom ActionSheet. When I do  I get some problems. The subview I am adding consists of one red view. This red view has constraints for its height, and horizontal and vertical space.

[image: xib]
<sub>(source: [bildr.no](https://bildr.no/image/cGJrcVlY.jpeg))</sub>

My problem is that the height does not seem to be correct on 4S and 5S devices. The view gets taller on the 5S than the 4S. I expected it to be the other way around as the 5S has more points than the 4S.

[image: Side by side]
<sub>(source: [bildr.no](https://bildr.no/image/SzdEQzNP.jpeg))</sub>

I add the subview with this code:

`[self.view addSubview:self.customActionSheet.view];
[self.customActionSheet viewWillAppear:NO];`

If I instead add the view by pushing it:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.customActionSheet animated:YES];`

Then the result is like I expected. The 4S is completely covered by the red view and the 5S still has some area above the red view.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using auto layout or autoresizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view does not auto resize according device screen. `[UINavigationController pushViewController: animated:]` will work because navigation controller set view's frame for you. The quick way to do is set your view's frame with current view.

```
self.customActionSheet.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

And do not invoke `viewWillAppear:` yourself, system will invoke it.

My suggestion is use auto layout to fulfil your view to superview. Following code uses PureLayout: https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout

```
[self.view addSubview:self.customActionSheet.view]
[self.customActionSheet.view autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to add constraints to `self.customActionSheet.view`.

When you load a controller view by `pushViewController:animated:` message, the system add the view the constraints needed so it fills all screen space.

Instead, if you add it manually (via `addSubview:` message), autoulayouts constrains are not created automatically, and you need to create and add them to the view programmatically.

I post here an example of what you may need so you `customActionSheet` fills all screen space:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *left = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:self.customActionSheet.view
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:self.customActionSheet.view
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:self.customActionSheet.view
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:0];


NSLayoutConstraint *right = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.customActionSheet.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];

[self.view addSubview:self.customActionSheet.view];
[self.view addConstraints:@[left, right, top, bottom]];
```

Comment: The constraints were already added in the xib-file. Sorry for not explaining that.